# Is there a standard best way to join unrelated single-row/value results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT 
    values, fee, values + fee AS total 
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS joint, SUM(value) AS values 
     FROM table_one 
     WHERE condition)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS joint, fee 
     FROM table_two 
     WHERE condition) f USING (joint);
```

I've never seen anyone do anything like this before, and I feel like I'm probably doing something stupid.  I'm not an experienced SQL dev.

I could retrieve them in separate queries, but it would make things uglier.

Edit: Assume table_one has one column: 'value', and table_two has columns: 'id' and 'fee' for the sake of this example.

Comment: Any reason not to do a `JOIN` directly on two tables?

Comment: @KassianSun What should I join on?

Comment: `FROM table_one LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_one.1 = table_two.1 WHERE table1_condition AND table2_condition`, depends on the actual table structure, I don't use `1` to reference columns personally.

Comment: @KassianSun That makes no sense, 1 isn't a column name.

Comment: You can just use `cross join` if you're just concatenating single-row-single-column results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @shawnt00:

CROSS JOIN is a simpler join for this scenario.

Another solution I've found since asking is

```
LEFT JOIN ON true
```